# Quotient of two integers not displaying in assembly

Tags: assembly, division, x86-16

A part of my code is supposed to get the sum, difference, product and quotient of two integers and display them. It works fine for the sum, difference and product. However, when it comes to the quotient, it's not displaying anything. Can anyone please explain why that is and if there is any way to work around it?
Thanks in advance!

```
printString result1
    plus:
        mov ax, firstInteger
        mov bx, secondInteger
        add ax, bx

        call printAns

    call printNewLine
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printString result2
    minus:
        mov ax, firstInteger
        mov bx, secondInteger
        sub ax, bx

        call printAns

    call printNewLine
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printString result3
    multiply:
        mov ax, firstInteger
        mov bx, secondInteger
        mul bx

        call printAns

    call printNewLine
; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    printString result4
    divide:
        mov ax, firstInteger
        mov bx, secondInteger
        div bx

        call printAns

    call printNewLine
```

printAns looks like this:

```
printAns proc
        xor cx, cx
        xor dx, dx
        xor bx, bx
        mov bx, 10
        loop1:  
            mov dx, 0000h       ;clears dx during jump
            div bx              ;divides ax by bx
            push dx             ;pushes dx(remainder) to stack
            inc cx              ;increments counter to track the number of digits
            cmp ax, 0           ;checks if there is still something in ax to divide
            jne loop1           ;jumps if ax is not zero

        loop2:  
            pop dx              ;pops from stack to dx
            add dx, 30h         ;converts to it's ascii equivalent
            mov ah, 02h     
            int 21h             ;calls dos to display character
            loop loop2          ;loops till cx equals zero
        xor ax, ax
        xor bx, bx
    ret
printAns endp
```

For example, if I input 9 as the first number and 3 as the second, this is what happens:
[image]

Comment: You forgot to zero `dx` before the division.

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much! I didn't realize it was that simple.

Comment: I just clicked a +1 on your question, because you have commented it sufficiently well for it to make sense; something that few people here do.

Answer (score 0):

The division misses the clearing of the DX register because a word division always divides DX:AX by the operand specified.

```
 printString result4
divide:
 mov ax, firstInteger
 xor dx, dx
 div secondInteger
 call printAns
 call printNewLine
```